# Formula Problem:Undefined control sequence

Tags: errors, tex-general

I  make use of following website: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 R(u,\Gamma)=\frac{\gamma}{2}\int_{\Omega\setminus \Gamma} \left |\triangledown  u \right |^2\partial x+\alpha\mathcal{H}_1(\Gamma)
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The right formula is as follows:
[image]

but after copy and paste procedure, I get following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 ...Omega\setminus \Gamma} \left |\triangledown
                                                    u \right |^2\partial x+\...

?
```

Comment: you need to `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton  5 seconds too slow:-)

Comment: Don't you want `\nabla` instead? By the way, remove `\left` and `\right` that do nothing good.

Answer (score 2):

`\triangledown` comes from `amssymb`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 R(u,\Gamma)=\frac{\gamma}{2}\int_{\Omega\setminus \Gamma} \left |\triangledown  u \right |^2\partial x+\alpha\mathcal{H}_1(\Gamma)
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The customary symbol in that context is `\nabla` rather than `\triangledown`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
R(u,\Gamma)=
\frac{\gamma}{2}\int_{\Omega\setminus\Gamma}
  \lvert\nabla u \rvert^2\,\partial x
+\alpha\mathcal{H}_1(\Gamma)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\lvert` instead of `\left|`, `\rvert` instead of `\right|` and `\,` in front of `\partial x`.